# Matching data in two tables

Tags: mysql, postgresql, join

I'm teaching myself SQL and I ran into a question that may be related to joining tables. I'm just a bit unsure.

Say, you have two tables, one listing the customer's `creditcard_number`, and one listing the customer's `order_number`. I am trying to match a customer's `creditcard_number` with their `order_number`.

What might this query look like? Would I first have to join the tables?

Comment: Please always provide basic table definitions to make things clear and easier to answer. Ideally also some sample data and the desired result.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter I provided some - would be interested in any comments you may have. I think that the OP is a bit before the step where they can provide real data?

Answer (score 4):

To give you a flavour of `JOIN`s and `SQL`, I created two tables - `Customer` and `Cust_Order` as shown.

I then loaded these tables with data (see end of post for DML). These examples use both PostgreSQL and MySQL. A note on table names. I use singular names - you can, of course, use plural (as many do) - but decide and stick to one!

A word of advice (and see discussion below), if you have a choice, I would **strongly** urge you to use PostgreSQL as its dialect of SQL is vastly superior to MySQL's. The `--` (double hyphen) is a comment in SQL, insert/remove as appropriate for your server.

```
CREATE TABLE Customer
(   
  Cust_ID SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,                 -- PostgreSQL
  -- Cust_ID  INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, -- for MySQL
  Name VARCHAR(15),
  CC_Number VARCHAR(16)
);

CREATE TABLE Cust_Order  -- don't want a table named "Order" - SQL keyword
(
  Order_ID SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,  -- PostgreSQL
  -- Order_ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, -- MySQL
  Cust_ID INT,
  Order_Value INT,
  Order_DateTime TIMESTAMP,  -- PostgreSQL
  -- Order_DateTime DATETIME -- MySQL
  CONSTRAINT Order_Cust_fk FOREIGN KEY (Cust_ID) REFERENCES Customer(Cust_ID)
);
```

Firstly, to answer your **specific** question about relating credit card number to the order, the query (for both PostgreSQL and MySQL) to run would be this:

```
SELECT c.Cust_ID, c.CC_Number, o.Order_ID
FROM Customer c
INNER JOIN Cust_Order o
ON c.Cust_ID = o.Cust_ID
ORDER BY c.Cust_ID;
```

which gives the result:

```
+---------+---------------+----------+
| Cust_ID | CC_Number     | Order_ID |
+---------+---------------+----------+
|       2 | 4656576576767 |        1 |
|       2 | 4656576576767 |        2 |
|       2 | 4656576576767 |        3 |
|       2 | 4656576576767 |        4 |
|       3 | 9999999999999 |        5 |
|       3 | 9999999999999 |        6 |
|       3 | 9999999999999 |        7 |
|       3 | 9999999999999 |        8 |
|       3 | 9999999999999 |        9 |
+---------+---------------+----------+
```

The reason that I didn't directly answer the specific question in your post was that it is **very** unlikely that anyone would be performing such queries. Storing credit card numbers as plain text is a recipe for disaster. Since the question related to `JOIN`s and `SQL` generally, I was more interested in demonstrating `JOIN`ing and `SQL` than in how to display CC numbers.

SQL is all about aggregations and `GROUP`ing and `SUM`ming, so in my original example, I showed the SUM of sales by Customer and CC number (although, as mentioned, you should **never** be performing `SQL` against CC numbers directly). Chances are you'll be interested in sales per customer rather than actual CC numbers.

```
SELECT c.Cust_ID, c.Name, c.CC_Number, SUM(o.Order_Value) AS Total
FROM Customer c 
INNER JOIN Cust_Order o 
ON c.Cust_ID = o.Cust_ID
GROUP BY c.Cust_ID, o.Cust_ID                      -- PostgreSQL GROUP BY
-- GROUP BY c.Cust_ID, c.Name, c.CC_Number, o.Cust_ID -- MySQL GROUP BY
ORDER BY o.Cust_ID;
```

result:

```
+---------+-------+---------------+-------+
| Cust_ID | Name  | CC_Number     | Total |
+---------+-------+---------------+-------+
|       2 | Jimmi | 4656576576767 | 13736 |
|       3 | Mary  | 9999999999999 | 27775 |
+---------+-------+---------------+-------+
```

**A word of warning about MySQL:**

MySQL has a variable `sql_mode` which is a set of parameters - you can view it by issuing the command 'SELECT @@sql_mode;' in the `mysql` client (or MySQL Workbench). You can set it in the my.cnf or my.ini (Windows) in the `mysqld` section:

```
[mysqld]

sql_mode    = "STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY"
```

The `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` parameter is the one to set, otherwise MySQL can produce (ahem...) anomalous (i.e. **wrong**) results!

Finally, and to expand, you might also (as someone who's selling widgets :-) ) be interested in clients who haven't bought anything (possibly in a specified period). I wrote this query using a `LEFT JOIN` (not `INNER`). This works for PostgreSQL and MySQL.

The `LEFT JOIN` will bring in everything in the left (or first, i.e. Customer) table - i.e. **all** clients whether they've made purchases or not, i.e. whether they have a corresponding entry in the Cust_Order table or not. The `INNER JOIN` will only match records which correspond in both tables - i.e. it will only show clients to whom a sale has actually been made.

```
SELECT c.Cust_ID, c.Name, c.CC_Number, COALESCE(SUM(o.Order_Value), 0) AS Total
FROM Customer c 
LEFT JOIN Cust_Order o 
ON c.Cust_ID = o.Cust_ID
-- WHERE EXTRACT(MONTH FROM Order_DateTime) = 2        -- PostgreSQL
-- WHERE MONTH(Order_DateTime) = 2                     -- MySQL
GROUP BY c.Cust_ID, o.Cust_ID                          -- PostgreSQL
-- GROUP BY c.Cust_ID, c.Name, c.CC_Number, o.Cust_ID  -- MySQL
-- HAVING COALESCE(SUM(o.Order_Value), 0) >= 0
-- ORDER BY SUM(o.Order_Value) NULLS FIRST, c.Cust_ID ASC;  -- PostgreSQL
-- ORDER BY SUM(o.Order_Value) IS NULL DESC, c.Cust_ID ASC; -- MySQL
```

Result:

```
 cust_id | name  |   cc_number   | total 
---------+-------+---------------+-------
       3 | Mary  | 9999999999999 | 27775
       2 | Jimmi | 4656576576767 | 13736
       4 | Joe   | 2222222222222 |     0
       1 | Billy | 3434343434343 |     0
```

This is the result with no `WHERE`, `HAVING` or `ORDER BY` clauses.

I would urge you to experiment with the `COALESCE` function ([PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/functions-conditional.html) and [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/comparison-operators.html)) and instead just using `SUM`(o.Order_Value) - instructive for `NULL`s. Vary it both in the `SELECT`, the `HAVING` and the `ORDER BY`.

Check out the `EXTRACT` ([PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-datetime.html)) here and `MONTH` ([MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html)) functions and the other functions on those pages. Vary the `SUM` in the `HAVING` and the `ORDER BY` - go mad!! :-)

These servers (as do others) have string functions ([PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-string.html) and [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html)) and also maths ones ([P](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-math.html) and [M](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mathematical-functions.html)) - as well as regular expressions (much better supported in PostgreSQL than MySQL - another reason to use PostgreSQL).

This should get you started on the road to SQL mastery! :-)

Take a look at the questions on this forum and make an attempt to answer
them - you'll gradually find that situations that used to baffle
you become clearer.

===================== **Data for Queries** ===========================

Customer table data:, for both PostgreSQL and MySQL.

```
 INSERT INTO Customer (Name, CC_Number) VALUES ('Billy', '3434343434343');
 INSERT INTO Customer (Name, CC_Number) VALUES ('Jimmi', '4656576576767');
 INSERT INTO Customer (Name, CC_Number) VALUES ('Mary',  '9999999999999');
 INSERT INTO Customer (Name, CC_Number) VALUES ('Joe',   '2222222222222');
```

Cust_Order table data: (again, for both PostgreSQL and MySQL).

```
INSERT INTO Cust_Order (Cust_ID, Order_Value, Order_Datetime) VALUES (2, 3434, '2105-02-14 11:55:34');
INSERT INTO Cust_Order (Cust_ID, Order_Value, Order_Datetime) VALUES (2, 3434, '2105-02-18 14:24:34');
INSERT INTO Cust_Order (Cust_ID, Order_Value, Order_Datetime) VALUES (2, 3434, '2105-03-09 09:23:17');
INSERT INTO Cust_Order (Cust_ID, Order_Value, Order_Datetime) VALUES (2, 3434, '2105-03-27 16:02:56');
INSERT INTO Cust_Order (Cust_ID, Order_Value, Order_Datetime) VALUES (3, 5555, '2105-01-22 12:45:03');
INSERT INTO Cust_Order (Cust_ID, Order_Value, Order_Datetime) VALUES (3, 5555, '2105-02-25 13:34:43');
INSERT INTO Cust_Order (Cust_ID, Order_Value, Order_Datetime) VALUES (3, 5555, '2105-02-28 17:50:01');
INSERT INTO Cust_Order (Cust_ID, Order_Value, Order_Datetime) VALUES (3, 5555, '2105-03-01 18:30:16');
INSERT INTO Cust_Order (Cust_ID, Order_Value, Order_Datetime) VALUES (3, 5555, '2105-03-17 11:17:17');
```

Comment: Your query will fail in Postgres: "*column "c.cust_id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function*"

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name but it will succeed if we use `GROUP BY c.Cust_ID`  and 9.1+ ;) http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d1ea41/2

Comment: @ypercube: I know that, but it will not work as it is shown right now using `o.Cust_ID`.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I agree 100%. I expect Verace to edit - especially since he is suggesting Postgres as a better product, I expect answers to be checked first. Plus the query doesn't really gives us the `order_number`, as asked in the question.

Comment: @ypercube edit on the way. There appears to be a bug in MySQL (or at least a gotcha!) - trying to figure it out.

Comment: @Vérace , the `GROUP BY` behaviour of MySQL is well known. It is being corrected in 5.7 version after many years of weirdness. See [Why does MySQL add a feature that conflicts with SQL standards?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7594865/why-does-mysql-add-a-feature-that-conflicts-with-sql-standards) for some explanation and links with more info.

Comment: This has come up before - I happen to use a couple of different machines - have ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY set on Linux, but not on Windows :-(. That has now changed! Edit still on way - considerable revision taking some time (+ end-users!).

Comment: @ypercube - thanks for the links (and the critique) - that darn old ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY strikes again! Anyway, I think that I've done a good job on the revised post - covers the OP's actual question and what I believe they were really after - at least to a point, on both PostgreSQL and MySQL. One thing though, I'm confused by the `GROUP BY`s for the two queries GROUP BY c.Cust_ID, o.Cust_ID                      -- PostgreSQL GROUP BY
GROUP BY c.Cust_ID, c.Name, c.CC_Number, o.Cust_ID -- MySQL GROUP BY - perhaps you could explain what exactly is going on?

Comment: @ypercube - revised post **again**. Whoever said that in order to learn something, you first had to teach it was right. Any comments welcome.

Comment: Very nice to see MySQL and Postgres side-by-side to compare. For the Postgres part, I would have too much to comment on. Here is how I would calculate total orders for all customers: `SELECT Cust_ID, c.Name, c.CC_Number, o.total
FROM   Customer c 
LEFT   JOIN (
   SELECT Cust_ID, SUM(o.Order_Value) AS total
   FROM   Cust_Order
   GROUP  BY Cust_ID
   ) o USING (Cust_ID)
ORDER BY Cust_ID;`

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter - thanks for your input. The query that you posted needs to remove the "o." in "o.Order_Value" (change just to "Order_Value") in the sub`SELECT` - otherwise server gets confused (both PostgreSQL and MySQL). Would be interested in "For the Postgres part, I would have too much to comment on" - that's precisely what I'm interested in - trying to learn! Even just a couple of links would be good - I'm trying to get a handle on what might be termed your "Zeitgeist" :-) in the sense of at least a hint of what you mean by potential comments. Sorry to pester, anyway, thanks.